# Upper bound on expectation of n non independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, expectation, order-statistics

Given $X_i$ are (not necessarily independent) and $\max_{j \leq n} (E|X_j|^p)^{1/p} = \sigma_p < \infty$, $p>1$

Prove that : $E\ \max_{j \leq n} |X_j| \leq n^{1/p} \sigma_p$

### Approach:

$$
E\ \max|X_i| \leq E\ \max|X_i|^P \leq \sum_{j \leq n} E|X_j|^p \leq n\ \max E|X_j|^p = n\sigma_p^p
$$

Comment: Start with $E\ \max|X_i| \leq (E\ \max|X_i|^p)^{1/p}$ and continue as you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Probability_measure) (or Lyapunov's inequality),
$$
\operatorname E|X|\le(\operatorname E|X|^p)^{1/p}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\operatorname E\max_{i\le n}|X_i|
\le(\operatorname E\max_{i\le n}|X_i|^p)^{1/p}
\le\biggl(\operatorname E\biggl[\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|^p\biggr]\biggr)^{1/p}
\le (n\sigma_p^p)^{1/p}
=n^{1/p}\sigma_p.
$$